# Why won't this sequence of entities sort in the GridView after binding?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, linq-to-entities

This sequence I created works well in LINQPad

```
IQueryable<AccessRequest> filteredRows1;
// retrieve the last record of each request in its request history
filteredRows1 = from req in AccessRequestSet
    group req by req.TaskReferenceId
    into g
    let topReq = g.OrderByDescending(r => r.UpdateDate).FirstOrDefault()
    select topReq;

IQueryable<AccessRequest> filteredRows = 
    filteredRows1.Where(o => o.Status == "Requested");
```

I want to then sort these entities by the field, RequestedReleaseTime.

```
filteredRows.OrderBy(p => p.RequestedReleaseTime);
```

Again I'm grouping by one DateTime successfully, and then sorting by another DateTime successfully, confirmed in LINQPad. I then add this as a DataSource and bind to my GridView:

```
gvRequests.DataSourceID = string.Empty;
            gvRequests.DataSource = filteredRows;
            gvRequests.DataBind();
```

I have even set AllowSorting="true" and added this line to Sort.

```
gvRequests.Sort("RequestedReleaseTime", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

I have tried this last line before and after the DataBind to no avail. What is wrong with this approach? Should I be doing any of this within the OnSorted or OnSorting events? Note: I tried that and got StackOverflowException, which reminded me that I should be asking you guys. Thanks millions for any direction or help I receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `OrderBy` doesn't actually modify the original query, but instead returns a new query based on the original, which you need to pick up:

```
var filteredRowsOrdered = filteredRows.OrderBy(p => p.RequestedReleaseTime);
```

I believe the gridview's "sort" is intended to work with something like an ObjectDataSource, which knows to call a method to retrieve the data and pass a sort string into that method. Unfortunately, this doesn't work very well with Entity Framework. We've figured out some tricks to make our data-access classes figure out how to convert a sort expression into a `q = q.OrderBy(...)` statement. But it can be complicated.

Comment: Good point, like strings they are immutable. I actually use the altered query in my application. The code above came from what I did in LINQPad to test it. I was hoping that there was an obvious fix.

Comment: @Blanthor: If you're setting the data source to the ordered query (what in my example is filteredRowOrdered), it ought to be ordering correctly.